# Formula for $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}^4$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

May I know where I can read/find simpler formula for $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}^4?$$

I tried to use generating function trick just like in the squared case, but I lost it as the multiplication is too much..and I feel like it is not gonna work the same but I tried it anyway xD

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Wolfram gives a closed-form expression in terms of hypergeometric functions.

Comment: The hypergeometric expression from Wolfram is `HypergeometricPFQ[{-n,-n,-n,-n},{1,1,1},1]` which is exactly the same as the binomial sum since the hypergeometric in this case is a finite terminating sum.

Comment: OK. I will to search for Hypergeometric function stuff stuff..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [A005260](http://oeis.org/A005260) in the OEIS.  The nicest expression they give (in my opinion) is this recursive one:
$$
a_{n} = \frac{1}{n^3}\left((4n - 2)(3n^2 - 3n + 1)\cdot a_{n-1} + (4n - 3)(4n - 4)(4n - 5)\cdot a_{n-2}\right)
$$
for $n \ge 2$ (with $a_0=1$ and $a_1=2$).

Comment: Wow. Can this really be explicitly solved? Comments suggest something about hypergeometric function. Is that the explicit formula for the above relation or a different one?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an *approximation*, you could use
$$\log\left( \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}^4\right)\sim \frac{27608 }{9977}n+\frac{2 }{2669}n \log (n)-\frac{3919 }{2839}\log
   (n)-\frac{15533}{9047}$$

For $n=50$, the exact value is
$$1141414024819789256187074524647238375882479333861915381768$$ while this *approximation* would give
$$1150625550178599919625707223110892786861320701420884344305$$

Comment: A moment. The last line is from taking natural exponent of the log, right?

Comment: @21understanding. This is correct